# How to show a zoomed part of a graph within a MATLAB plot?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot, matlab-figure

I have about four series of data on a Matlab plot, two of them are quite close and can only be differentiated with a zoom. How do I depict the zoomed part within the existing plot for the viewer. I have checked similar posts but the answers seem very unclear.

I look for something like this:

[image]

Comment: [`zoom()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html)? I suggest you add some images to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve. It isn't clear to me what exactly you're asking and where your problem is.

Comment: you can set the x and y axis limits but add some images of the problem

Comment: Use `tikz` :P You can probably do something like that in MATLAB, but its just not the rigth tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion how to do this with MATLAB. It may need some fine tuning, but it will give you the result:

```
function pan = zoomin(ax,areaToMagnify,panPosition)
% AX is a handle to the axes to magnify
% AREATOMAGNIFY is the area to magnify, given by a 4-element vector that defines the
%      lower-left and upper-right corners of a rectangle [x1 y1 x2 y2]
% PANPOSTION is the position of the magnifying pan in the figure, defined by
%        the normalized units of the figure [x y w h]
%

fig = ax.Parent;
pan = copyobj(ax,fig);
pan.Position = panPosition;
pan.XLim = areaToMagnify([1 3]);
pan.YLim = areaToMagnify([2 4]);
pan.XTick = [];
pan.YTick = [];
rectangle(ax,'Position',...
    [areaToMagnify(1:2) areaToMagnify(3:4)-areaToMagnify(1:2)])
xy = ax2annot(ax,areaToMagnify([1 4;3 2]));
annotation(fig,'line',[xy(1,1) panPosition(1)],...
    [xy(1,2) panPosition(2)+panPosition(4)],'Color','k')
annotation(fig,'line',[xy(2,1) panPosition(1)+panPosition(3)],...
    [xy(2,2) panPosition(2)],'Color','k')
end

function anxy = ax2annot(ax,xy)
% This function converts the axis unites to the figure normalized unites
% AX is a handle to the figure
% XY is a n-by-2 matrix, where the first column is the x values and the
% second is the y values
% ANXY is a matrix in the same size of XY, but with all the values
% converted to normalized units

pos = ax.Position;
%   white area * ((value - axis min) / axis length)   + gray area
normx = pos(3)*((xy(:,1)-ax.XLim(1))./range(ax.XLim))+ pos(1);
normy = pos(4)*((xy(:,2)-ax.YLim(1))./range(ax.YLim))+ pos(2);
anxy = [normx normy];
end
```

Note that the units of `areaToMagnify` are like the axis units, while the units of `panPosition` are between 0 to 1, like the `position` property in MATLAB.

Here is an example:

```
x = -5:0.1:5;
subplot(3,3,[4 5 7 8])
plot(x,cos(x-2),x,sin(x),x,-x-0.5,x,0.1.*x+0.1)
ax = gca;
area = [-0.4 -0.4 0.25 0.25];
inlarge = subplot(3,3,3);
panpos = inlarge.Position;
delete(inlarge);
inlarge = zoomin(ax,area,panpos);
title(inlarge,'Zoom in')
```

[image: zoomin]

Comment: Highly recommended answer!

Comment: how to delete lines which connect the plot and "zoom in"?

Comment: Just remove this part from the function: `annotation(fig,'line',[xy(1,1) panPosition(1)],...
    [xy(1,2) panPosition(2)+panPosition(4)],'Color','k')
annotation(fig,'line',[xy(2,1) panPosition(1)+panPosition(3)],...
    [xy(2,2) panPosition(2)],'Color','k')`

Comment: how to zoome two part of the plot using your function?